# Serpientes y Escaleras - Python Turtle

Tags: python

Estoy desarrollando el juego de escaleras y serpientes con python turtle graphics. Pero tengo un problema, la tortuga azul o jugador 1. No se porque al llegar al **punto 60** del tablero este pasa de largo, aun si continuo agregando mas lineas **no pasa del 60**, y no continua hasta la posicion 100 del tablero. Dejo una captura.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede ver continua de largo, en vez de subir al punto 61, hasta llegar al 100. Aviso que va linea por linea subiendo. Habré hecho algo mal. Lo otro que no se como dibujar unas escaleras, no se muy bien como hacerlo. Eso agradezco la ayuda, gracias.

Este es mi codigo, **comentado**.

```
from turtle import *
from random import choice,randint
x = -250
y = -250

#CREACION TABLERO
i =0
speed(5000)
penup()
goto(x,y)

while(i < 100):



pendown()
forward(50)
left(90)
forward(50)
left(90)
forward(50)
left(90)
forward(50)
penup()
goto((x+22), (y+22))
#write(abs(i+1))

#goto((x-25),(y-25))
left(90)
x = x +50
goto(x,y)
i+=1
a = str(i)
if x == 250:
    if (i%10 ==0):
        penup()
        y = y+50
        x=-250
        goto(x,y)

i=0

x = -250
y = -250

while i<100:
    penup()
    goto((x+22), (y+22))
    write(abs(i+1))
    i = i +1

    x = x +50

    if x == 250:
        penup()
        y = y+100
        x=-250
        goto(x,y)
        i= i+10

a = 250
b = -200
i = 10

while i<100:
    penup()
    goto((a-26),(b+22))
    write(i+1)
    i = i+1
    a = a-50
    if a ==-250:
        penup()
        b = b +100
        a = 250
        goto(a,b)
        i = i +10

#FIN TABLERO

#SERPIENTES

serpientes = []
for _ in range(8):
    s = choice((-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5))
    s = s*50
    sf =choice((-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5))
    sf = sf *50
    if s ==250:
        s = s-44
    if s == -250:
        s = s + 44
    if sf ==250:
        sf = sf-44
    if sf == -250:
        sf = sf + 44    

serpientes.append((s+22,sf+22))
print(serpientes)    

i=0
while i <= 6:

    goto(serpientes[i])
    pendown()
    pen(pencolor = "green",pensize= 5)
    goto(serpientes[i+1])
    penup()
    i = i+2

#ESCALERAS
escaleras = dict()
i = 0
x = 0
while len(escaleras) != 8:
    s = choice((-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5))
    s = s*50
    sf =choice((-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5))
    sf = sf *50
    if s ==250:
        s = s-44
    if s == -250:
        s = s + 44
    if sf ==250:
        sf = sf-44
    if sf == -250:
        sf = sf + 44  

if (a,sf) not in escaleras and (a,sf) not in serpientes:
    escaleras[i]=((s+22,sf+22))
i = i+1     


print(escaleras)    

i=0
d = 0
while i <= 6:

    goto(escaleras[i])
    write(1)
    pendown()
    pen(pencolor = "brown",pensize= 5)
    goto(escaleras[i+1])
    write(2)
    penup()
    i = i+2    

#tortuga A

a = Turtle()
a.shape("turtle")
a.color("green")
a.penup()

a.goto(-270,-228)


#tortuga B

b = Turtle()
b.shape("turtle")
b.color("blue")
b.penup()

b.goto(-272,-228)
speed(1)
#manejo turtlesb

#tortuga C

c = Turtle()
c.shape("turtle")
c.color("yellow")
c.penup()
c.goto(-270,-228)


#Aca esta la funcionalidad

tecla = 0
while tecla != 9:
    print("precione enter para lanzar dado")
    input()
    tecla = randint(1,6)


    print(tecla)

for _ in range(tecla):
    if b.pos() ==(228,-228): #10
        b.left(90)
    if b.pos() ==(228,-178): #11
        b.left(90)  
    if b.pos() ==(-222,-178): #20
        b.right(90)   
    if b.pos() == (-222,-128): #21
        b.right(90) 
    if b.pos()==(228,-128): #30
        b.left(90)         
    if b.pos()==(228,-78):  #31
        b.left(90) 
    if b.pos() ==(-222,-78): #40
        b.right(90)
    if b.pos() ==(-222,-28): #41
        b.right(90)     
    if b.pos() ==(228,-28): #50
        b.left(90)  
    if b.pos() ==(228,22): #51
        b.left(90)
    if b.pos() == (-222,22): #60 aca no funciona deberia girar hacia arriba y subir despues :/
        b.right(90)


    b.forward(50)   
    print(b.pos()) 

done()
```

Comment: Hola buenas podrías compartir como te quedo tu código al final

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es un error de representación en coma flotante que te pasa desapercibido por el redondeo que hace el método `__str__` del objeto `Vec2D` que retorna `pos`. Si en vez de `print(b.pos())` haces `print(f"({b.xcor()}, {b.ycor()})")` te encuentras que en la casilla 60 tienes :

```
(-222.0, 22.000000000000064)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comparar floats usando una igualdad a secas es peliagudo por su imprecisión intrínseca debido a la [representación en coma flotante](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coma_flotante), puedes ver la siguiente entrada en la documentación de Python también:

- [Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)

La solución depende del caso, desde usar rangos para comparar, redondeos, truncamientos, etc. Otra posibilidad es usar [`math.isclose`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isclose).

Por otro lado, en vez de crear tantos condicionales y complicarte la vida, puedes recorrer todo el tablero usando simplemente cuatro apoyándote en el ángulo, el cual puedes obtener con el método `heading` y asignar con `setheading()`:

```
import math


for _ in range(tecla):
    b.forward(50)
    x, y = b.pos()
    angle = b.heading()

    if math.isclose(x, 228, rel_tol=1e-03):
        if angle == 0:
            b.setheading(90)
        elif angle == 90:
            b.setheading(180)
    elif math.isclose(x, -222, rel_tol=1e-03):
        if angle == 180:
            b.setheading(90)
        elif angle == 90:
            b.setheading(0)
```

También deberíamos tener cuidado con el ángulo, pero en éste caso con valores 0, 90 y 180 no deberemos tener problemas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias, voy a leer la documentacion, creo que la pase por alto antes al no leerla. Lo probe y funciona.

Comment: Es importante tener siempre ésto presente, no es un problema de Python, es común a cualquier lenguaje cuando se usa el estándar IEEE 754. Lo que si me parece no se si un bug, pero al menos confuso, es que `Vec2D.__repr__()` también retorne `(-222.0, 22.0)` en mi opinión que eso ocurra con  `__str__`  (usado por `print`) lo entiendo, pero `__repr__` debería mostrar algo acorde a lo que hace `b.ycor`, porque como no lo sospeches te vuelves loco viendo como te dice una y otra vez que `(-222.0, 22.0) != (-222, 22)`....